# WindowsServer 2008R2 64-bit IIS Framework64 folder; error 500.21 with ashx

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, aspnet-regiis.exe

I'm getting a 500.21 error when trying to call an ashx I've written (it works fine on my development PC on localhost); one of the most likely causes of the error, according to the verbose error page on the server, is `ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely`.

When Windows Server 2008R2 is running on a 64-bit server, my assumption is that it is necessary to execute commands such as the following *only in the Framework64 folder*, not in the 32-bit folder as well. Is that assumption correct?

```
  run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
  run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Answer (score 0):

We tried both commands and didn't solve the problem.
500.21 response with PUT verbs.

Apparently the WebDAV module will block both the DELETE and PUT (update) verbs for IIS.

The only way we managed to solve this was removing WebDAV from the handlers of the site adding the following lines to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

more info: http://forums.iis.net/t/1166025.aspx